# Why can't I nullify the style of TR

Tags: javascript, html

The TR has an initial style I want to set to "". I tried to do it with cssText property but it doesn't work (must also work with IE8)

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    tr.test {background-color:#000000;margin:0;border:0;padding:0;}
  </style>

</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr  style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: silver; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">
    <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>

<script>
_table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
_tbody = _table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
_tr = _tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
_tr.cssText = "";
_tr.className="test";
</script>
```

Comment: Just use `_tr.style = ""`? And you should really use `var` to declare your variables.

Comment: A simpler approach that works in all browsers is adding and removing classes. Why are you using inline styles to set multiple style properties? Use a class, and then later remove the class.

Answer (score 1):

`cssText` is a property of a style rule, not of an HTML element.

```
_tr.style.cssText = "";
```