# How can I change style attribute using setAttribute instead of using style.cssText on IE8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I can change TR style on IE 8 with :

```
 _tr.style.cssText = "";
```

But I have a bunch of properties which are NOT ONLY STYLE (id, align, etc...) - I don't know at design time - to change and want to do all at once generically with setAttribute.

```
 _tr.setAttribute("style", "")
```

works in Chrome and IE Edge but not on IE 8. Is there another syntax for IE 8 ?

Update : I know IE8 is a nightmare but I'm on a big corp project who will only switch to modern IE at the end of the year.

Comment: What's wrong with `_tr.style.prop = value;` to set any given style property to a new value.

Comment: And, how is this question supposed to be different than your previous question from 30 minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35820819/why-cant-i-nullify-the-style-of-tr.  You should generally edit a question to clarify it, not post another similar question.

Comment: `setAttribute` is broken in old-IE. You already have the alternative syntax in your question. Why are you supporting IE 8 anyway? It is past end of life and doesn't get security updates any more. It shouldn't be allowed out onto the WWW.

Comment: I'm also more than happy to tell any IE8 user that tries to use my site that there are so few of them and their browser is so horrible that it's not worth my time to try to support them.  Get a real browser and they can happily use my site.

Comment: Why aren't you using classes? If you have "a bunch" of things to change, create a class with those changes and add it to the element. Put the original inline style settings in a class and then later remove that class. Works in all browsers...

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object literal for your attributes and add them via for/in loop:

```
<div id="test">This is a test</div>
<script>
    var div = document.getElementById('test');
    var styles = {'color':'#ff0000', 'backgroundColor':'#00ff00', 'width':'500px', 'height':'250px'};
    for (var style in styles) {
        div.style[style] = styles[style];
    }
</script>
```

As a side question: Is a separate css class not the better solution?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention it's not only style